# React renders component upon NavLink click but crashed upon refresh

Tags: reactjs

I have a component Dashboard.js that will render upon NavLink click, but upon refresh the page crashes. I am stumped about what to do.

The error says `cannot read properties of undefinded (Budget)`

Upon NavLink click, the page will not render the chart using "goalsChartData." When I refresh, the whole thing crashes. If I navigate to '/home' then click back on Dashboard.js, the budget data does populate the chart/the page loads, but still from here if I refresh, it crashes.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  LineChart,
  Line,
} from "recharts";

const Dashboard = ({ user, budget, personBudget }) => {
  // data for Goals Chart
  // data for Goals Chart
  // data for Goals Chart
  const goalsChartData = [
    {
      name: "Week 1",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekOneGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 2",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekTwoGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 3",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekThreeGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 4",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekFourGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 5",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekFiveGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 6",
      Goal: user.budget ? user.budget.weekSixGoals : null,
    },
  ];

  // data for Friends Chart
  // data for Friends Chart
  // data for Friends Chart
  const friendsChartData = [
    {
      name: "Week 1",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekOneGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekOneGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekOneGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 2",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekTwoGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekTwoGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekTwoGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 3",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekThreeGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekThreeGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekThreeGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 4",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekFourGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekFourGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekFourGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 5",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekFiveGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekFiveGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekFiveGoals : null,
    },
    {
      name: "Week 6",
      Person1: personBudget[0] ? personBudget[0].weekSixGoals : null,
      Person2: personBudget[1] ? personBudget[1].weekSixGoals : null,
      Person3: personBudget[2] ? personBudget[2].weekSixGoals : null,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "grey",
        display: "grid",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Your Goals</h4>
      <BarChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={goalsChartData}
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
        barSize={30}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" scale="point" padding={{ left: 10, right: 10 }} />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <Bar dataKey="Goal" fill="#8884d8" />
      </BarChart>
      <LineChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={friendsChartData}
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="Person2"
          stroke="#8884d8"
          strokeDasharray="5 5"
        />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="Person1"
          stroke="#82ca9d"
          strokeDasharray="3 4 5 2"
        />{" "}
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="Person3"
          stroke="#e21c7f"
          strokeDasharray="3 4 5 2"
        />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import RequireAuth from "./pages/RequireAuth";
import useStyles from "./pages/useStyles";
import Budget from "./components/Goals";
import ProfileDelete from "./pages/ProfileDelete";
import People from "./components/People";
import Friends from "./components/Friends";
import Person from "./components/Person";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Goals from "./components/Goals";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [userFriends, setUserFriends] = useState([]);
  const [budget, setBudget] = useState([]);
  const [personBudget, setPersonBudget] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/authorize_user").then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then((user) => {
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
          setUser(user);
        });
      }
    });
    fetch("/people").then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(setPeople);
      }
    });
    fetch("/friends").then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(setUserFriends);
      }
    });
    fetch("/budgets").then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(setBudget);
      }
    });
    fetch("/person_budgets").then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(setPersonBudget);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {

  // }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Paper className={classes.pageContent} elevation={24}>
        <Navbar
          user={user}
          setUser={setUser}
          isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
          setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
        />
      </Paper>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="login"
          element={
            <Login
              user={user}
              setUser={setUser}
              isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
              setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="signup"
          element={
            <Signup
              user={user}
              setUser={setUser}
              isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
              setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="home"
          element={
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
              <Home />{" "}
            </Paper>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="profile"
          element={
            // <RequireAuth isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
              <Profile
                user={user}
                setUser={setUser}
                isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
              />
            </Paper>
            //{" "}
            // </RequireAuth>s
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="goals"
          element={
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
              <Goals user={user} budget={budget} />
            </Paper>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="profile/delete"
          element={
            <ProfileDelete
              user={user}
              setUser={setUser}
              setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="people"
          element={
            <People
              people={people}
              user={user}
              setUser={setUser}
              setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
              userFriends={userFriends}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/friends"
          element={
            <Friends user={user} userFriends={userFriends} people={people} />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/people/:id"
          element={
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
              <Person
                user={user}
                people={people}
                userFriends={userFriends}
                setUserFriends={setUserFriends}
              />
            </Paper>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="dashboard"
          element={
            <Dashboard
              user={user}
              budget={budget}
              personBudget={personBudget}
            />
          }
        />
        {/* <Route path="goals" element={<Goals user={user} />} /> */}
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your API requests haven't finished loading yet which is why you are getting the undefined.
For this scenario you need to include a loading state so something like this would work.

App.js

```js
function App() {
  ... all of your code above render

  const loaded = people && userFriends && budget && personBudget;

  if (!loaded){
    return '...loading'
  }
  
  return (
    ...what you already have in your render
  )
}
```

Though I would encourage you to refactor your code as this many api calls and setStates in one file will cause a lot of re-renders. I would encourage you to look at the `useContext` hook and create a provider for each of those api calls rather than have them all in the app.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers. I am a student trying to bang something together before due date in two days. I initially tried to use Redux Toolkit but I couldn't gain traction with it. I'm not sure how to implement your answer.. when you say "...what you already have in your render", does that mean to put everything thats currently inside my useEffect, inside that?

Comment: Yep thats right. Because there is quite a bit of code in your file I didn't want to write it all out so I just added those comments to show where the rest of your code needs to go.
I would encourage you to enhance this more past your due date. Having this many api calls in one file isnt really that good. You could just have a function outside of your component that does it all for you. Or like I mentioned use the `useContext` hook which removes the need for something like Redux. Happy to help out students so feel free to send me an email if you want more clarification.

Comment: ok, something like this? https://gist.github.com/m-delc/a151f343a66072d2e5b296144f63b786 where i totally leave out useEffect but I just put the fetch calls inside that if/else

Comment: Thank you so very much Richard, I just emailed you.

Comment: No I mean outside of your `App` component all together, fetch all of your api data and then use a `useEffect` within `App` that calls the function.
PS. try not to use this as a discussion area as thats not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I dont get it, but thanks anyway.